# Django left join with users table

Tags: python, django

I am working on a system in python Django where I have to fetch a list of users with their profile picture. I have a model containing user photos. Users can upload multiple photos and can set only one of them to be the profile picture.

Here is my Photo model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  

class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    is_main = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to fetch all users and main Photo for each user if they have. Something like the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` `u` 
LEFT JOIN `photos` `p`
ON `u`.`id`=`p`.`user_id`
AND `p`.`is_main`=True
```

What's the Django ORM for the above query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the custom [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) objects:

```
photos = Prefetch('photo_set',
                  queryset=Photo.objects.filter(is_main=True),
                  to_attr='main_photo')
users = User.objects.all().prefetch_related(photos)
for user in users:
  # user.main_photo[0] contains the photo
```

Comment: It worked. I couldn't access the main_photo list in the template so I had to loop through the users reassigning main_photo[0] to another variable. Thanks.

Comment: You could access it as `{{ user.main_photo.0 }}`. Please mark the question as accepted if you feel it's the solution.